# Code Completion is too small in ABAP editor

Tags: editor, abap

Code completion is too small in ABAP backend editor (SE38/SE80), how to make it big?

[image: code completion box is cropped]

My ABAP release is 7.4 and I have the below settings :

[image: SAP GUI code completion settings]

Comment: Undoubtedly a bug. You should tell us what are the versions of your softwares, or install the latest SAP GUI version (cf note [1607121 - ABAP Editor: Quick info dialog box is too small](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1607121))

Comment: Sandra, The note you gave is 7.2 but we are using 7.4 Release

Comment: 7.2 is no ABAP release but SAP GUI release. Check the version of SAP GUI that you have installed locally on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, this can usually be remedied by changing the Display Settings. Adjust scaling to 100% and try this again. The code completion help should scale correctly, regardless, but in the meantime this is a viable workaround.